# Setting custom user-agent in GTK Webkit

Tags: c, gtk, webkit

I create a GTK window in C by

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
 GtkWidget*window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

 WebKitWebContext * context =   webkit_web_context_new ();

 GtkWidget* view = webkit_web_view_new_with_context(context);
 WebKitSettings*settings = webkit_web_view_get_settings(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(view));
 webkit_settings_set_enable_javascript(settings,true);
 webkit_web_view_set_settings(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(view),settings);


 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),view);
 webkit_web_view_load_uri(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(view),"https://www.whatsmyua.info/");
 gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 1440, 900);
 gtk_widget_show_all(window);
 gtk_main();
 return 0;
}
```

How can I set a custom user-agent instead of the original one?

The GTK and Webkit2 libraries have been installed from the official repository of Ubuntu 22.04.